# Is there a good tutorial about the new block-based animations with MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin.ios, core-animation

Is there a good tutorial about the new block-based animations with MonoTouch?

All I know is that instead of the usual method:

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("ImageMove");

//code to make changes to the view (move controls, swap views, etc.)

UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

...the new block-based animation method, available from iOS 4.0, uses:

```
UIView.Animate(0.2, () => { /* code to animate */ });
```

or:

```
UIView.Animate(0.2, delegate() { /* code to animate */ });
```

But a more extensive tutorial would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `monotouch`'s block-based animation, the method is:

```
Animate(double, double, UIViewAnimationOptions, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction)
//Animate( animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion )
```

You can refer it [HERE](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView%2fM%2fAnimate).

Code sample like this:

```
UIView.Animate(0.2, () => { /* code to animate */ });
```

or

```
UIView.Animate(0.2, delegate() { /* code to animate */ });
```

And [HERE](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewAnimationOptions) is a enumeration list for `UIViewAnimationOptions`.

---

I use the method below to do block-based animation for `cocoa-touch`, paste the code here maybe someone else need:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
```

Detail description is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                      delay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                    options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#>
                 animations:<#^(void)animations#>
                 completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>];
```

You can do animation like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Do your animtion here;
                     [yourViewController.view setAlpha:0.0];
                     // ...
                 }
                 completion:^{
                     if (finished) {
                         // Do sth that after the animation
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: @Krumelur nope, it's available in iOS 4.0 and later. :) You can refer to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).